# sql error on converting varchar to int while there is no int parameter in my code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a sp which is for inserting data to my table. In my sp I have a field tracingno that most of my implemented code is related to that.  but I encounter with this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SRFCHE-600-R-1000000' to data type int.
>   type of tracingno is varchar but I cant get why I facing with this error.

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[spInsertRecieptTracing_tblRecieptTracing]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    drop procedure [dbo].[spInsertRecieptTracing_tblRecieptTracing]
GO

create procedure spInsertRecieptTracing_tblRecieptTracing (
    @RecieptTracingID UniqueIdentifier,
    @RecieptItemRef UniqueIdentifier,
    @TracingNo varchar(4000),
    @ExecuteID UniqueIdentifier, 
    @Quantity Decimal(25,5),
    @ExpireDateStr varchar(4000),
    @ExpireDate datetime,
    @ManufacturingDateStr varchar(4000),
    @LotNo varchar(4000),
    @IsBarCode Bit,
    @ManufacturingDate DateTime,
    @PartOptionName varchar(1000) = null,
    @partcode varchar (100)
)
with Encryption
as 

declare @_tracingno varchar (1000)
if  exists ( 
    select * 
    from ims.tblsettings where IsPartInTracingno = 1
)
begin
    if exists (
        select top 1 TracingNo 
        from ims.tblRecieptTracing 
        where TracingNo like '%-%')
    begin

    set @_tracingno = (
        select max( right(TracingNo, charindex('-', reverse(TracingNo) + '-') - 1)) 
        from ims.tblRecieptTracing
    )

    end
    else
    begin
        set @_tracingno = 1000000
    end
end
else
begin 
    set @_tracingno=''
end

if(@IsBarCode is null)
    set @IsBarCode =0;

if(@IsBarCode =0)
    begin
        SET @TracingNo = NULL;
    end


IF(EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM IMS.tblRecieptTracing 
    WHERE RecieptItemRef = @RecieptItemRef 
 ) and @IsBarCode = 0)
    update IMS.tblRecieptTracing 
    set ExecuteID=@ExecuteID, 
        Quantity = @Quantity, 
        ExpireDateStr = @ExpireDateStr, 
        ExpireDate = @ExpireDate, 
        PartOptionName = @PartOptionName
    Where RecieptItemRef = @RecieptItemRef

ELSE 
    BEGIN
    if(@TracingNo is null)
    begin
        if exists(select * from ims.tblsettings where IsPartInTracingno=1)
        begin
            SELECT @TracingNo = @partcode + '-' + cast(@_tracingno as varchar) 
            FROM IMS.tblRecieptTracing ;
            IF(@TracingNo IS NULL ) 
            begin
                SET @TracingNo = 1000000;
                SET @TracingNo = @TracingNo +1 ;
            end
            SET @TracingNo=cast (@TracingNo as varchar)
        end
        else
                --select 
            SELECT @TracingNo = cast (max( right(TracingNo, charindex('-', reverse(TracingNo) + '-') - 1))as varchar) 
            from ims.tblRecieptTracing;
            IF(@TracingNo IS NULL ) 
                SET @TracingNo = 1000000;

            SET @TracingNo = @TracingNo + 1 ;
        end

            insert into IMS.tblRecieptTracing ( 
                RecieptTracingID , 
                RecieptItemRef , 
                TracingNo  ,  
                ExecuteID ,  
                Quantity ,
                ExpireDateStr ,
                ExpireDate,
                ManufacturingDateStr,
                LotNo,
                ManufacturingDate,
                PartOptionName)
            values( 
                @RecieptTracingID, 
                @RecieptItemRef, 
                @TracingNo , 
                @ExecuteID , 
                @Quantity ,
                @ExpireDateStr ,
                @ExpireDate,
                @ManufacturingDateStr,
                @LotNo,
                @ManufacturingDate,
                @PartOptionName);
        END
```

I think the main part is here:

```
SELECT @TracingNo=cast (max( right(TracingNo, charindex('-', reverse(TracingNo) + '-') - 1))as varchar) from ims.tblRecieptTracing;
```

Comment: at the second `SET @TracingNo = @TracingNo +1 ;` you have no begin end sourrunding, maybe it's the problem, But with begin end it doesn't make sence, you could simply write `SET @TracingNo = 1000001;`

Comment: The full error message will tell you the line number.

Comment: I'd need the table structure for tblRecieptTracing and tblsettings to reproduce. sample data helps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99 times out of a 100, this error is caused by the fact that SQL Server tries to implicitly convert a character expression to int.

**TL;DR;**
Somewhere in your code you are attempting to either compare, combine or populate an int value with the character value `'SRFCHE-600-R-1000000'`.

From the [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) documentation:

> Data types can be converted in the following scenarios:
>
> - When data from one object is moved to, compared with, or combined with data from another object, the data may have to be converted from the data type of one object to the data type of the other.
> - When data from a Transact-SQL result column, return code, or output parameter is moved into a program variable, the data must be converted from the SQL Server system data type to the data type of the variable.

And further down the same page:

> Data types can be converted either implicitly or explicitly.
>
> Implicit conversions are not visible to the user. SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. For example, when a `smallint` is compared to an `int`, the `smallint` is implicitly converted to `int` before the comparison proceeds.

What type of data would be implicitly converted to what other type is documented in [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1 user-defined data types (highest)
> 2 sql_variant
> 3 xml
> 4 datetimeoffset
> 5 datetime2
> 6 datetime
> 7 smalldatetime
> 8 date
> 9 time
> 10 float
> 11 real
> 12 decimal
> 13 money
> 14 smallmoney
> 15 bigint
> 16 int
> 17 smallint
> 18 tinyint
> 19 bit
> 20 ntext
> 21 text
> 22 image
> 23 timestamp
> 24 uniqueidentifier
> 25 nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26 nchar
> 27 varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28 char
> 29 varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30 binary (lowest)

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to this line:

```
SET @TracingNo = @TracingNo + 1 ;
```

You should change this to

```
SET @TracingNo = @TracingNo + '1' ;
```

---

Check out Zohar Peled's excellent answer: nvarchar has lower priority (25) than int (16).

Thus, when you calculate

```
@TracingNo + 1
```

the engine will take the nvarchar values of @TracingNo and the integer 1. In order to add them, it will try to convert the lower priority datatype term to the higher one. Thus, it will try to convert @TracingNo to int. This is exactly what the error message is about: One of your @TracingNo values cannot be converted to int.

Comment: was my first thought too, so I tested it, and with an int value even inside a varchar is works well enough, at the time of his error the value was "SRFCHE-600-R-1000000" which would definitely throw the error shown and I see no place int the logic that would allow that situation to occur.

Comment: Are you sure your test is correct? Here is some small code that exactly replicates the error:  `declare @x nvarchar(max); set @x='SRFCHE-600-R-1000000'+1;`

Comment: that always errors, but I can't find where the string is left without stripping out the extra values before the int operations are processed. All previous to number related operations he strips off the non-number chunks. but it does give me an idea. maybe I didn't express myself clearly.

Comment: If you copy-paste the OP's code to an editor, you will find the error at both lines 84 and 95

Comment: previous operation to both 84 and 95 is "SET @TracingNo = 1000000", no errors parsing, no errors for estimate execution plan, though it is generally unwise to use a varchar this way it is within the scope of implicit conversion if the value is good inside. I see no way that, prior to int operations, that this would still be the old value with chars and -s.