# SQL - Search based on type (Int & VarChar)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to perform a combined search based on fixed, known references (Int) and also wildcard's (varchar) on different columns.

My integer search works fine, but by varchar (LIKE) search fails with a varchar to int conversion failure.

```
WHERE
MyID = 1 AND MyRef = @Search OR
MyID = 1 AND MyName LIKE N'%' + @Search + N'%'
```

I'm assuming that the failure is when SQL is searching for a varchar against the int (MyRef)

Where have I gone wrong ?
thanks in advance

Comment: I personally always use parens especially if there is both an 'AND" and an 'OR' in the query.  Sometimes the default 'order of operations' gives what is wanted, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will try to [implicitly convert strings to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197934/sql-error-on-converting-varchar-to-int-while-there-is-no-int-parameter-in-my-cod/55204705#55204705) whenever you compare, move or concatenate a number to a string. 
To avoid it, you must explicitly convert the number to a string:

```
WHERE MyId = 1 
AND 
(
    MyRef = @Search 
    OR MyName LIKE N'%' + CAST(@Search as varchar(11)) + N'%'
)
```

I'm using `varchar(11)` because it's just big enough to hold the minimum value of `int`, including the minus sign. If the number is of a different type, you might want to choose a different size.

I've also rearranged your conditions a little bit - there's no point of having the same condition multiple times, and also, it's always good to use parenthesis when combining `and` and `or` in the same `where` clause.

Comment: As `MyRef` is an `INT`, comparing it to a `VARCHAR(11)` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to use `concat()`:

```
WHERE MyID = 1 AND
      ( MyRef = @Search OR
        MyName LIKE CONCAT('%', @Search , '%')
      )
```

However, something doesn't seem comfortable about this.  Do you really want the same search term for both fields?

Answer (score 1):

Does this return the expected result?

```
where MyId = 1 and 
case isnumeric(@search) when 1 then 
       case when myRef = @search then 1 else 0 end
   else 
       case when MyName like N'%' + @search + N'%' then 1 else 0 end
   end = 1
```

or

```
where MyId = 1 and 
case try_cast(@search as int) when is not null then 
       case when myRef = @search then 1 else 0 end
   else 
       case when MyName like N'%' + @search + N'%' then 1 else 0 end
   end = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I decided against combining all search parameters into one, instead i've split out the reference search and the text search.